# How to classify domain and file name using regex?

Tags: regex

I am using a regex, which matches both the domain and file name.

https://regexr.com/4bmm4

Domain: google.com

File:   sample.txt

Which is the best way to distinguish between domain and file?

Comment: There could exist the possibility that a domain name collides with an extension of a file.  At least, this could always be possible.

Comment: Is it a good idea to hard code known file types? Is there any library which does a similar task?

Comment: Yes, you could either try to proceed using a whitelist of domain names, or a whitelist of file names, but again, someone could name a text file `stuff.com`, and your logic might still flag it as being a domain.

Comment: since you are using regexr as your tool, you can find some from "community patterns" under menu.